# SSRS URL Security with ASPX Page

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

Is there any way of of accessing SSRS URL server using specific user authority via an ASPX page yet not allow users to access this URL  via direct access in a browser.

Reason for this is we have a user creating their own html pages with links to these reports therefore bypassing our application security.

I do not want to use the reportview control on the page as this presents problems in ie7 (sorry but we still support it) and also renders much slower than directly referencing the SSRS server

SSRS Server is SSRS 2008R2, Web Server Windows 2008, vb .NET4 aspx

Thanks in advance

**To Further explain**

We have a web application which where we have implemented security which can be controlled at a user or group of users

e.g

UserA has access to Report1 and not Report2
UserB has access to Report2 and not Report1

UserB can get hold of the URL for report2 and provide it to UserA hence bypassing our menu security.
We have allowed 'browser' access to all out reports on the SSRS server to our users (and I know this is what's enabling the security bypass)
I don't want to maintain security in 2 locations (i.e in the application and in SSRS).

Is there any way of locking down SSRS to use an impersonation profile rather than the profile the user is logged on as without requesting authentication

Comment: Couldn't you make an HttpWebRequest?

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused by your statement:

> Reason for this is we have a user creating their own html pages with
>   links to these reports therefore bypassing our application security.

I don't buy this.

If you setup SSRS with proper security, no user can "bypass it" with a HTML page.
Can you please elaborate how you have setup your security model on your SSRS installation?

In theory, you could design a proxy web application that does no impersonation to the back end SSRS,  only via a service account, and that way only expose a limited set of links. 
But that shouldn't be necessary.